# May we have the Markup GUI as available on the official free demo?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am building a UI for creating Markups in my app. Actually, I am trying to recreate The markups GUI as shown here:
[image]
I find this UI to be perfect. If I were to build one myself, I would do it exactly this way. The one included with the viewer works perfectly, but it is ugly (Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui). I am speaking for others as well here, but it would be appreciated if we could have access to the UI that is being used here as a ready-to-go extension: https://viewer.autodesk.com/

Or any other alternatives that do not mean having to rebuild the entire extension, pretty please?

Thank you :)

Comment: I don't think the code of this app is published by Autodesk. I understand the UI is pretty nice in this app. All the functions are binded with this UI even the default toolbar which is included in different ways. It's only web development, it's not a big deal ! You don't have to recreate the entire extension. `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui` rely on `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore`, do the same with you custom UI !

Comment: As @AlexAR said, those UI's are not public, but you can create your own